# scp doesn't work when my .bashrc is echoing to console

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, scp

Ok, so I have used linux for a long time but this is the weirdest thing I have encountered in a long time. Maybe I just don't do a lot of scp so probably missing something simple here. So in my .bashrc file I have the following.

```
export KERNEL=$(uname -r)
#echo "HOST: $HOSTNAME: KERNEL VERSION: $KERNEL"
if [ $KERNEL == "2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64" ];then
   ... logic here
else
    .. more logic
fi
```

Now if I uncomment that echo line then the following command doesn't work! It just shows the echo but doesn't do any copying. If I remove that line it does the copy

```
$ scp -r host1.net:/prod/path1/path2/dir1/etc /tmp/user/sim/dir1
HOST: host1.net: KERNEL VERSION: 3.4.70-1.el6.companyX


$ scp -r host1.net:/prod/path1/path2/dir1/etc /tmp/user/sim/dir1
```

pybackup                                                                                                                      100%  174     0.2KB/s   00:00
Proxy.ini                                                                                                                     100%  623     0.6KB/s   00:00

This is strange...

Comment: I happened to find a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12442753

Answer (score 2):

Using echo in a .bashrc will break scp, as scp expects to see its protocol data over the stdin/stdout channels. See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=20527 and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440287/scp-doesnt-work-when-echo-in-bashrc/12442753#12442753) for more discussion on this issue.

There's a few workarounds available, how to use echo in a scp-safe manner in .bashrc:

```
case $- in *i*) echo Hello World ; esac
tty >/dev/null && echo Hello World
if [ -t 1 ]; then echo Hello World ; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the first lines of my (default) `.bashrc` file:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

The check for an interactive session avoids messing up with SCP, SFTP or `ssh remote-host command` mode.

Without this, if your file `.bashrc` uses `echo` or some other stuff printing on stdout, you may get this kind of errors:

- SFTP : `Received message too long 168435779`
- SCP : `protocol error: unexpected <newline>`