# Using sftp like scp

Tags: linux, openssh, sftp, scp

As OpenSSH guys said ["The scp protocol is outdated"](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.0), it's time to think about post-scp days.

However `sftp` seems to be designed to interactive operation.
Is there good way to use `sftp` command like `scp`? 
means, how to do this on `sftp`?

```
scp ./myfile myserver:/home/myfile
```

Or, any good `scp` successor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since OpenSSH 8.7, `scp` can use SFTP protocol. Just add `-s` switch:

```
scp -s ./myfile myserver:/home/myfile
```

Since [OpenSSH 9.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0) the `scp` uses SFTP by default.

---

[`sftp` command](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp) is indeed built around commands (like `ftp`). So it cannot work as an in-place replacement for `scp`.

Though you can use one-liners like:

```
echo get /remote/path/file.txt /local/path.txt | sftp user@example.com
```

or

```
echo put /local/path.txt /remote/path/file.txt | sftp user@example.com
```

You may want to add `-b -` to force a non-interactive mode.

---

Interestingly (as @Kamil mentioned), for downloads, you can also use this `scp`-like syntax:

```
sftp user@example.com:/remote/path/file.txt /local/path.txt
```

(the use of the second argument is not documented).

Use of `sftp://` prefix is also possible since OpenSSH 7.7, which somewhat modifies the syntax (allows URL encoding of the username and the path).

---

There's also free/open-source [`pscp` command-line client](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp) that comes in PuTTY package, which is available for Linux (while more commonly used on Windows). It has an *identical* command-line interface to OpenSSH `scp`. Similarly to recent versions of OpenSSH `scp`, `pscp` is primarily an SFTP client (while it can fallback to SCP, if the server does not support SFTP).

> Despite its name, PSCP (like many other ostensible scp clients) can use either of these protocols.
>
> ...
>
> Normally PSCP will attempt to use the SFTP protocol, and only fall back to the SCP protocol if SFTP is not available on the server.

You can install PuTTY/pscp with `apt-get` like:

```
sudo apt-get install -y putty
```

---

There's similar question on Stack Overflow:
[Single line sftp from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16721891/850848)

Comment: In `scp` from `OpenSSH_8.8p1` I see that the parameter to use SFTP is `-s`. From the man page: `-s      Use the SFTP protocol for transfers rather than the original scp protocol.` Unfortunately they did not add an option for this for `.ssh/config` :( (or I do not see it)

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider rsync.  Except for the remote1-to-remote2 transfer that scp allows, it appears -- from a quick read of `man scp` anyway -- that you could make rsync do all of that quite easily, or write a wrapper that is not too painless.

Rsync has other advantages that you get by default (viz., much more efficient when replacing an older file), even if you don't use any of it's many options.